# According to Reformed Theology how can we saved by Grace 'Alone' and Faith 'Alone'?

Tags: faith, reformed-theology, grace, sola-fide, sola-gratia

Two of the Five Solas are:

- Sola Gratia: Salvation by Grace Alone
- Sola Fide: Justification by Faith Alone

If salvation is by "grace alone", how can "faith alone" be added as well? Only one of these two should be chosen in order to use the term "alone". From scripture grace and faith work together, e.g.:

> ... we have also obtained access by faith into this grace in which we stand ... *(Romans 5:2, ESV)*
>
> For by grace you have been saved through faith. *(Ephesians 2:8, ESV)*

Suppose someone builds a bridge over a chasm to rescue a group of hikers from a great disaster, and announces to all hikers that the bridge has been built. Arriving on the safe side, someone tells the hikers: "You arrived here *only* through the goodwill of the bridgebuilder", and "You arrived here *only* because you actually crossed the bridge". How logical is that? Clearly, the two must work together (and not together, although separately alone)?

Comment: Salvation and Justification are not (according to adherents of the 5 solas) the same thing.

Comment: I think your bridge example demonstrates the distinction more than you realize.  To assume a question like "How did you get here?" can be answered by both responses places a certain equivocation on the meaning of "how" and its relation to the basis of arrival.  It might help to consider more explicitly what the two responses are actually answering: How did you travel from there to here? (by crossing the bridge) How did the bridge come to be? (by the goodwill of the bridgebuilder)   Both responses are valid (even in their exclusivity), because they're really answering different questions.

Answer (score 6):

These two slogans were used to explain two major disagreements Protestants had with what the Catholic Church was teaching, and yes, they are designed to work together! They don't compete, they are alone in their own respective fields.

**Sola Fide** refers to the belief that works are not a means or prerequisite for salvation. People are declared to be justified (righteous) purely on the basis of trusting God to fulfil his promise to save us through the gracious act of Jesus taking the hit for us on the cross. This was the major defining belief of the Protestant reformation.

**Sola Gratia** refers to the belief that nothing a person does contributes to their salvation. From God's perspective no person has ever merited any component of their salvation - salvation is purely a gift (grace) from God. There is a lot of overlap between this and Sola Fide. But it means that the game never changes. Once you're saved you still live on the basis of grace and faith. The good works Christians do will never be anything other than graces from God. I've also heard that it is a kind of summary of the other Solas: Our faith is a gift from God, not something we produce ourselves. Christ Alone means we come to God purely through Jesus, with no human mediators. Grace Alone means that Jesus was never obligated to do anything, especially not come to the earth and die - every action of God is a gift. Similarly God was never obligated to reveal himself to us through scripture - the Bible is a gift.

The two work together, and many Protestants will say that we are saved "by grace through faith", exactly what your verse from Ephesians says.

Comment: If these two solas don't compete, and there is a lot of overlap, how can each one still attempt to claim exclusivity? Neither grace (provided by God) nor faith (man's response by accepting Christ) should be viewed in isolation. It is the combination of the two that brings about salvation.

Comment: They claim exclusivity *in their respective fields*.

Comment: Their respective fields overlap, and the two solas cannot therefore be exclusive?

Comment: @aslan I don't understand what the issue is. In respect to how we are justified, we are justified by faith alone. I respect to what our works contribute, they contribute nothing for it is grace alone.\

Comment: @curiousdannii Is it possible to be justified and not be saved (or saved but not justified)? I agree that salvation cannot be earned through works, and that faith is not part of works (but still an action or response on man's part).

Comment: @aslan Protestants would say that's not possible. So would Catholics I think.

Comment: @curiousdannii indeed we would.

Comment: @aslan You assume their respective fields overlap. I think that's where you're confused (and this answer does not clarify). In Reformed Protestant parlance Justification and Salvation are not referring to the same thing. The rest of this answer is fine as far as it goes, but it would be much better to include the difference between those issues so it's clear why a separate "alone" can be used when referring to the prerequisites.

Comment: @Caleb If I understand correctly, justification refers to the legal standing acquired by faith, being made righteous in God's sight. Salvation refers to being free from God's judgement, acquired by grace. Doesn't justification then imply salvation and vice versa? If so, grace and faith are linked inseparably and what purpose is served by attempting to make them exclusive?

Comment: @Aslan It's complicated because there are a lot of potential schemes that the Protestants were trying to rule out. Grace Alone says that our works are worthless and we must rely on God's grace. But you could suggest that even though human works are worthless that we earn God's merit through our own works. Faith Alone rules that out.

Comment: @curiousdannii If salvation is by grace alone, that would imply no faith is required (to obtain salvation), and if justification is by faith alone that would imply no grace is required (to obtain justification). From Rom 5 "...obtained access by faith into this grace..." and other scriptures it doesn't seem that we should isolate faith and grace. I understand the Protestants formulated statements in their battle against dogma that salvation can be earned or bought, but scripture alone should govern our understanding of faith and grace.

Comment: @aslan I don't understand what issue you have with what I've been saying. Yes they work together. No they aren't isolated.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree with "Yes they work together. No they aren't isolated", and therefore I don't fully agree with the view conveyed by these two solas.